# Convert String to Number and print to command line

Tags: string, haskell, ghc

I am working through Chapter 1 exercises of [Scheme in 48 hours](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/First_Steps). For question number 2, I'd like to convert a string to a number using the `read` function, but the code below doesn't work.

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    myNum <- read $ args !! 0
    putStrLn myNum
```

Here's the error message from ghc:

```
ex2.hs:7:12:
    No instance for (Read (IO t0)) arising from a use of ‘read’
    In the expression: read
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: one <- read $ (args !! 0)
    In the expression:
      do { args <- getArgs;
           myNum <- read $ (args !! 0);
           putStrLn myNum }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things wrong here.

First, to save variables in this function, you need to use the `let variable = "something"` type of statement rather than the `<-` binding operator. Here, `let myNum = read (args !! 0)` that takes the first command line argument.

Next, we use `read` to convert `myNum` to an anything type, but we need to also explicitly define the type (I chose *Float* for this example) to print the output back to the command line. Otherwise you'll get an error message like, `"Prelude.read: no parse"`

The code to convert from String to Number back to String looks like the following...

```
main = do
    -- get command line arguments
    args <- getArgs

    -- get the first indexed element; convert it from string to float
    let myNum = read (args !! 0) :: Float

    -- print this number to the command line (as a string)
    putStrLn (show myNum)
```